# gcloud appengine go1.11: cannot serve static files

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I have a go 1.11 app with following directory:

`./language
./models
./system
./public
./public/templates
./public/templates/home
./public/templates/layouts
./public/templates/partials
./public/templates/partials/frontend
./public/assets
./public/assets/css
./public/assets/js
./public/assets/img
./public/assets/icon
./public/assets/fonts
./conf
./handlers`

And my app.yaml:

```
runtime: go111

handlers:
- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon.ico
  secure: always

- url: /((?:img|css|js|icon|fonts)/(.*))$
  static_files: public/assets/\1
  upload: public/assets/
  http_headers:
    X-Foo: bar
  secure: always

- url: ./*
  script: auto
  secure: always
```

Everything works locally with dev_appserver.py, but I get 404s for all my static assets once I deploy to AppEngine. Ideas?

Comment: got the same issue. did overcome that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add:

```
- url: /static
  static_dir: public
```